# Expected response code 220 but got code "500", with message "500 Unknown command Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello guys I'm trying to send an email in laravel bu the thing is it is throwing me this error. Can somebody please explain to why am I facing this error. Here is the my code:

```
Route::get('testmail', function () {



  /*  \Mail::send('emails.test', array(), function ($m)  {
        $m->from('contrivesol@gmail.com', 's2c Mobile');
        $m->subject('Review Request For ');
        $m->to("gardezisyedmuhammadali@gmail.com", "Gardezi");
    });
*/

    $user='';


     \Mail::send('emails.test', ['user' => null], function ($m) use ($user) {
            $m->from('contrivesol@gmail.com', 'Your Application');

            $m->to('ovaiz.mushtaq@gmail.com', 'Awais')->subject('Your Reminder!');
        });



});
```

Here is the screenshot to my error log

[error_log](http://i.prntscr.com/757bd87983e64cc8b05b973fb7e071ca.png)

```
[2016-09-07 13:50:18] production.ERROR: exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 220 but got code "500", with message "500 Unknown command
"' in /var/www/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:383
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(281): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_assertResponseCode('500 Unknown com...', Array)
#1 /var/www/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(270): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('STARTTLS\r\n', Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(313): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->executeCommand('STARTTLS\r\n', Array)
#3 /var/www/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(118): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->_doHeloCommand()
#4 /var/www/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(79): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start()
#5 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(366): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message), Array)
#6 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(168): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->sendSwiftMessage(Object(Swift_Message))
#7 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(216): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->send('emails.test', Array, Object(Closure))
#8 /var/www/app/Http/routes.php(34): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('send', Array)
#9 /var/www/app/Http/routes.php(34): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::send('emails.test', Array, Object(Closure))
#10 [internal function]: RRS\Providers\RouteServiceProvider->{closure}()
#11 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(157): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#12 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(129): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runCallable(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(701): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(101): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(703): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#19 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(670): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(628): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(214): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /var/www/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(46): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(125): Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(43): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 /var/www/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(125): RRS\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#29 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(55): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(125): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#31 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(61): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(125): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#33 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(36): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(125): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#35 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(40): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#36 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(125): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#37 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(42): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(125): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(101): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(115): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#42 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(84): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#43 /var/www/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#44 {main}
```

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: @aynber you mean ==> storages => logs ??

Comment: Yes, it should be there.

Comment: @aynber here is the screenshot to the error log [error log](http://i.prntscr.com/757bd87983e64cc8b05b973fb7e071ca.png)

Comment: Access denied. It would be better to post the log lines here, rather than a screenshot elsewhere.

Comment: @aynber addded the error log

Comment: The mail server you're using doesn't support TLS.  Check with them for the proper settings.

Comment: @aynber I'm using mail catcher at the moment. So yeah you were right at that point but it should not give me problem with amazon or gmail. It is throwing me this error on gmail and amazon to/

Comment: If you're getting the "STARTLES Unknown Command" on gmail and amazon, you'll need to contact them.

Comment: You also need to set up gmail to accept less secure connection in order it work properly with laravels 5.2

Comment: @ericevans i have done that.

Answer (score 4):

Its about setting in your .env:

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```

Based on this answer:
[Laravel default mail not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192133/laravel-default-mail-not-working)